# strange malloc behavior with Doug Lea allocator

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, pic, microchip

I have an very small system with only 16kb of heap, no mmap, no swap. I'm using the latest version 2.8.5 of Doug Lea allocator ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc-2.8.5.c

**UPDATE I made a smaller test case that is easier to understand and see what is my problem**

If I allocate 8kb, free it, allocate 12kb, it's working (i != NULL), I can allocate the 12 kb:

```
char *i;
dlstats();
i = dlmalloc(8192);
printf("DEBUG: %p\n", i);
dlstats();
dlfree(i);
dlstats();
i = dlmalloc(12288);
printf("DEBUG: %p\n", i);
dlstats();
dlfree(i);
dlstats();
```

displays:

```
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa00003f0 arena 0 ordblks 0 usmblks 0 uordblks 0 fordblks 0 keepcost 0
DEBUG: 0xa00003f8
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa0002440 arena 8272 ordblks 1 usmblks 8272 uordblks 8200 fordblks 72 keepcost 32
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa0002440 arena 8272 ordblks 1 usmblks 8272 uordblks 0 fordblks 8272 keepcost 8232
DEBUG: 0xa00003f8
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa0003460 arena 12400 ordblks 1 usmblks 12400 uordblks 12296 fordblks 104 keepcost 64
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa0003460 arena 12400 ordblks 1 usmblks 12400 uordblks 0 fordblks 12400 keepcost 12360
```

If I first allocate a too big buffer (30kb) and then I allocate 8kb, free it, allocate 12kb, it's working (i == NULL), i *cannot* allocate the 12 kb:

```
char *i;
dlstats();
i = dlmalloc(30000);
printf("DEBUG: %p\n", i);
dlstats();
i = dlmalloc(8192);
printf("DEBUG: %p\n", i);
dlstats();
dlfree(i);
dlstats();
i = dlmalloc(12288);
printf("DEBUG: %p\n", i);
dlstats();
dlfree(i);
dlstats();
```

displays:

```
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa00003f0 arena 0 ordblks 0 usmblks 0 uordblks 0 fordblks 0 keepcost 0
DEBUG: 0x0
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa00003f0 arena 0 ordblks 0 usmblks 0 uordblks 0 fordblks 0 keepcost 0
DEBUG: 0xa00003f8
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa0002430 arena 8256 ordblks 1 usmblks 8256 uordblks 8200 fordblks 56 keepcost 16
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa0002430 arena 8256 ordblks 1 usmblks 8256 uordblks 0 fordblks 8256 keepcost 8216
DEBUG: 0x0
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa0002430 arena 8256 ordblks 1 usmblks 8256 uordblks 0 fordblks 8256 keepcost 8216
heap 0xa00003f0 sbrk 0xa0002430 arena 8256 ordblks 1 usmblks 8256 uordblks 0 fordblks 8256 keepcost 8216
```

At every moment, only one allocation is made and freed before allocation another block so the memory should never be fragmented.

Comment: You are calling dlstats() inside your loop - are you sure this call doesn't itself require some memory on the heap? Have you tried it without the call to dlstats?

Comment: @Frank: dlstats doesn't allocate memory and i tried without calling them and i have the same behavior

Comment: I changed the test case to a simple one. It seems that calling malloc if a too big size is generating the problem, I don't understand why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the answer from Doug Lea:

> If an attempt to extend (or
>   initialize) contiguous sbrk's segment
>   fails, sysalloc marks the space as
>   non-contiguous, to avoid continual
>   re-failures which would otherwise
>   disrupt transitions from MORECORE to
>   MMAP when availble.
>
> This causes subsequent segments to not
>   be mergeable. There is currently no
>   way to override this behavior. But you
>   should be able to work around it by
>   removing lines 4113-4

```
  else
    disable_contiguous(m); /* Don't try contiguous path in the future */
```

> In the future, I'll consider adding a
>   way to control this in the course of
>   some other planned support for
>   page-protection

Answer (score 1):

I think this paragraph (from wikipedia, so no guarantees) explains why you are seeing this behaviour:

> dlmalloc has a fairly weak free space segment coalescer algorithm, mainly because free space coalescing tends to be extremely slow due to causing TLB cache exhaustion. It is called every (by default) 4096 free() operations and it works by iterating each of the segments previously requested from the system which were not contiguously returned by the system. It tries to identify large ranges of memory which contain no allocated blocks and breaking its segment into two with the free memory being returned to the system. This algorithm works well if dlmalloc is the sole user of the VM system, however if dlmalloc is used simultaneously with another allocator then dlmalloc's free space coalescer can fail to correctly identify opportunities for free memory release.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc#dlmalloc_and_its_derivatives

Comment: Are you sure this information is up-to-date? I thought that misguided "optimization" was removed...

Comment: @R no, not sure at all. It is in wikipedia and the description simply matched his simptoms.

Comment: I changed the test case, now, it cannot be related to the coalescing algo. Check the new test, the only difference is that it doesn't work if i first allocate a too big buffer.